# Energy density of primordial gravitational waves- two different results for the same quantity?

Tags: general-relativity, waves, cosmology, perturbation-theory, cosmological-inflation

I want to calculate the energy density of primordial gravitational waves, $Ω_{gw}$ in a specific time. The latter is in general given by the relation :
$Ω_{gw}(k,τ)= \frac{1}{\rho_{c}(τ)} \frac{d\rho_{gw}(τ)}{dlnk}$.

So, I must first estimate the quantity $\rho_{gw}$, which is defined by the 0-0 component of the energy momentum tensor ($T_{00}$). The problem is that I found two different types for $\rho_{gw}$:

1) $\rho_{gw}=T_{00}=\int{\frac{k^{3}}{2\pi^{2}}\frac{|h'_{k}|^{2}+k^{2}|h_{k}|^{2}}{\alpha^{2}} \frac{dk}{k}}$

2)  $\rho_{h}=\rho_{gw}=T_{00}=\frac{1}{16 \pi G \alpha^{2}} \int{\frac{d^{3}k}{(2\pi)^{3}}[|h'_{+,k}|^{2}+|h'_{\times ,k}|^{2}]},\\ $

in

- eq.(21) of https://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/0512014.pdf
- and eq.(C12) of https://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/0604176.pdf,

respectively. The indexes $+,\times $ denote the polarization of the wave.

For the two above equations (1) and (2) to be the same we must say that 
$$k^{2}|h_{k}|^{2} = |h'_{\times,k}|^{2}. $$ Can we claim something like that or is it something else that makes them equal, or at least makes the above densities equivalent?

Note: In the first link(Boyle) the energy momentum tensor for gravitational waves ($T_{\mu\nu}$) arises from the Einstein-Hilbert Lagrangian, and in the second case(Watanabe) from considerations of the Einstein equation; but I think the two ways are equivalent: is this also correct?